# Proof of (part of) Dunford-Pettis theorem using ultrafilters

Tags: measure-theory

In P.A. Meyer Probability and Potentials, part of the proof for the Dunford-Pettis theorem is given in Page 20 (Theorem T23). I am looking at the
proof of the following statement :

Let $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{L}^1(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$. If $\mathcal{H}$ is uniformly integrable then $\mathcal{H}$ is relatively compact in the weak 
topology $\sigma(\mathcal{L}^1,\mathcal{L}^\infty)$.

The proof starts by assuming an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathcal{H}$. Then, for each $X\in \mathcal{H}, E \in \Sigma$ he defines, the map 
$I_X(E) = \int_E XdP$. As $\mathcal{H}$ is UI by assumption, this $I_X(E)$ 
is uniformly bounded.  The author then says that $\lim_\mathcal{U} I_X(E)$ 
exists for every $E$.

My question is how can one guarantee the existence of the limit. I have not heard of ultrafilters before this but now I do know the definitions from Bourbaki (Topology I). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.